# Reauthorize access for Integromat/Zappirer

Tags: make.com

I am using integromat and I have my gmail account connected. I need to one a week reauthorize the API link or it stops working. According to Integromat documentation the problem is on Googles side that it revokes the permit after a week.

I should be able to keep the connection if I have google workspace paid account but I wanted to ask someone who has the experience if it works. (As well if it will work with my personal account, I don't need new email).

Thank you for help